# Page hit analysis with a cleaned csv log python

Tags: python, logging, filtering, logfile-analysis

Below is the code to try and clean my csv log, when i run the code i am getting an error;
**

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "page_hit_analysis.py", line
>   12, in 
>       line = parser(line)

**

```
import apache_log_parser
from collections import Counter
from pandas import DataFrame
import seaborn


parser = apache_log_parser.make_parser('%h %l %u %t "%r" %>s')

pages = []
with open('cleaned_log7.csv') as in_f:
    for line in in_f:
        line = parser(line)
        pages.append(line['request_url'])

counts = Counter(pages)

selected_pages = [pair[0] for pair in counts.most_common(5)]
print(selected_pages)

graph_pages = [page for page in pages if page in selected_pages]
data = DataFrame({'pages': graph_pages})
print(data)

plot = seaborn.countplot(data=data, x='pages', order=selected_pages)
plot.get_figure().savefig('pages_plot7.png')
```

The above code works with the uncleaned log but not with the cleaned one.

Comment: is there a reason to reuse the `line` variable?

Comment: Im not sure thats what it was like in the tutorial i learned this from, i dont get the error with the uncleaned sad access log

Comment: can you try changing to `l = parser(line)
        pages.append(l['request_url'])`

Comment: so when i removed the 2 lines under the for line in in_f and replace it with what you suggested i get a syntax error on the pages part.

Comment: Then you have more issues than just your original code, you need to address each one and do some debugging. Also don't add a comment that you get an error, update your question with the updated code and include the full error